# Definition of time-reversibility of flow of Hamilton's equations

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, time-reversal-symmetry

I cannot find a good, simple definition of *time-reversibility* of the flow $\phi_t$ of Hamilton's equations
$$
\dot{z} = J^{-1}\nabla_z H(z) \quad \text{where} \quad z = (q, p)^\top \quad \text{and} \quad J^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & I \\ -I & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I know that for an autonomous ODE (like the one above) one has $\phi_t^{-1} = \phi_{-t}$ so that if $z_t = \phi_t(z_0)$ then $z_0 = \phi_{-t}(z_t)$. But what is the definition of time reversibility? How do I write it down matematically as a property? I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Sometimes people say that when the Hamiltonian is separable $H(q, p) = V(q) + K(p)$ and the kinetic energy satisfies $K(p) = K(-p)$ then the inverse can also be written as $\psi_N \circ \phi_t \circ \psi_N$ where $\psi_N(q, p) = (q, -p)$ simply negates the momentum. It seems that this notion is related to time symmetry but not sure how

Comment: Something is wrong in your equation $~\phi_t$ is matrix and $~z_t$ is a vector?

Comment: @Eli $\phi_t$ is the flow of the equation, so $\phi_t(z)$ is a vector of the same size as $z$

Comment: Let $\eta \Big( (q,p) \Big) =(q,-p)$, then the definition of time reversibility for the flow is $$ \phi_{-t} = \eta \circ \phi_t \circ \eta. $$  See the proof for separable Hamiltonians with even Kinetic energy https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/698059/why-inverse-flow-of-separable-hamiltonian-with-even-kinetic-energy-can-be-writte?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, time reversibility means the following. Assume your generalized position and moments $(q, \, p) \, \in \, \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and let $$\psi_N :  \mathbb{R}^{2n} \to  \mathbb{R}^{2n}$$ is the involution $$\psi_N(q, \, p) = (q ,\, -p)$$ Then the hamiltonian system
\begin{align}
&\frac{dq}{dt} \,=\, \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q, \, p)\\
&\\
&\frac{dp}{dt} \,=- \,\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q, \, p)
\end{align}
is time reversible whenever if $\Phi^t(q,\,p)$ is the phase flow of the system of ODEs above, it satisfies the identity
$$\psi_N \circ \Phi^t  \,=\, \Phi^{-t} \circ \psi_N$$
which can be interpreted as the following: if a solution starts at an initial position $q$ with initial momentum (or think velocity) $p$, and evolves to a moment of time $t$ seconds in the future to a position and momentum $q(t), \, p(t)$, after which we invert the momentum (velocity) at time $t$ as $p(t) \mapsto -p(t)$, then if we go forward in time exactly $t$ more seconds from the moment $t$, we return to the initial position $q$, with corresponding momentum (velocity) $-p$, as if we have travelled backwards $-t$ seconds in time from $q(t), \, -p(t)$ back to $p, \, -p$. Hence the term time reversibility. In mathematical notation, the latter description looks like:
$$\Phi^{t} \circ  \psi_N \circ \Phi^t(q,\,p)  \,=\, (q, \, -p)\,=\,\psi_N(q, \, p)$$
Since $\psi_N$ is linear involution, its derivative is
$$D\psi_N \, =\, \psi_D \,=\, \begin{bmatrix} I & O \\ O & -I\end{bmatrix}$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}  \,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q, \, p)\\ - \,\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}(q, \, p)\end{bmatrix} \, =\, -\,
\begin{bmatrix} I & O \\ O & -I\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  \,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q, \, -p)\\ - \,\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}(q, \, -p)\end{bmatrix} $$ So finally the condition of time-reversibility of a hamiltonian system boils down to the property
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q, \, p) \, =\, -\, \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q, \, -p)\\
&\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}(q, \, p) \, =\, \frac{\partial H}{\partial q}(q, \, -p)
\end{align}