# Why inverse flow of separable Hamiltonian with even kinetic energy can be written like this?

Tags: differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, flow

> Why is it true that the inverse of the flow of a separable Hamiltonian with even kinetic energy can be written as $\phi_N \circ \varphi_t \circ \phi_N$ where $\varphi_t$ is the flow of the Hamiltonian ODE and $\phi_N(x, v) = (x, -v)$ flips the momentum?

### Background

Consider a separable Hamiltonian $H(x, v) = V(x) + K(v)$ where the kinetic energy is *even* $K(v) = K(-v)$. Let $\phi_t$ be the flow of the autonomous ODE system given by Hamilton's equations (here we set $z = (x, v)$)
$$
\dot{z} = J\nabla_z H(z) \qquad \text{where} \qquad J =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & I\\-I & 0   \end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \nabla_z H(z) = (\nabla_x V(x), \nabla_v K(v))
$$
Define the momentum reversal/negation/flip as $\phi_N(x, v) = (x, -v)$. I want to show that
$$
\varphi_t^{-1} = \phi_N \circ \varphi_t \circ \phi_N
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to show that the "momentum-flipped" $\phi_N\varphi_t\phi_N$ obeys the correct differential equation to be $\varphi_t^{-1}$:

The chain rule says
$$ \partial_t( \phi_N\varphi_t\phi_N) = \partial_t(\phi_N\varphi_t)\phi_N = (D\phi_N) \partial_t(\varphi_t)\phi_N$$
Now,
$$ D\phi_N = \begin{pmatrix} 1_x & 0 \\ 0 & -1_v \end{pmatrix}$$
and $\partial_t(\varphi_t) = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_v H(x,v) \\ -\partial_x H(x,v)\end{pmatrix}$, so
$$ \partial_t ( \phi_N\varphi_t\phi_N) = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_v H(x,-v) \\ \partial_xH(x,-v)\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, when $H$ is separable as $H(x,v) = V(x) + K(v)$, we get
$$ \partial_t \varphi_t^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_v K(-v) \\\partial_x V(x)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-\partial_v K(v) \\\partial_x V(x)\end{pmatrix}.$$

But at the same time, $\varphi_t^{-1} = \varphi_{-t}$ since flows form a 1-parameter group, and so
$$ \partial_t \varphi_t^{-1} = \partial_t \varphi_{-t} = -\partial_t \varphi_t = - \begin{pmatrix}\partial_v K(v) \\ -\partial_x V(x)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-\partial_v K(v) \\\partial_x V(x)\end{pmatrix},$$
which means that $\phi_N\phi_t\phi_N$ and $\varphi_t^{-1}$ obey the same differential equation, thus $\varphi_t^{-1} = \phi_N\phi_t\phi_N$ under suitable assumptions on $K$ and $V$ for a uniqueness theorem to apply.